# TF 2.6: Input 'resource' of 'AssignVariableOp' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of resource

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, typeerror

I am applying an autoencoder to categorical data. My code used to work just fine, but after updating to TF 2.6, it throws this error while attempting to save my model: `Input 'resource' of 'AssignVariableOp' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of resource.`

The data file can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jnblr3Ik88V_qd3N5EDkTkBtFu_E7ku1/view?usp=sharing

It is in tsv format.

Here is the code and full error traceback:

```
import csv
import sys
import numpy as np
import math
import os
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Embedding, Flatten, Reshape, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l1
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import tensorflow.keras.callbacks as kcb

def adjust_count(x) :
    if x<2 :
        return x
    else :
        return x-1

mutations = {}
mut_info = {}
sampleIDs = []
mapping = {
    "0|0":0,
    "0|1":1,
    "1|0":2,
    "1|1":3
}


SNP_vcf = "/my/dir/in/chr1_SNPs_50785418_51253612_fh.vcf" 
outdir = "/my/dir/out/"
threshold = 1

chromosome, foo, start, end, _ = SNP_vcf.split('/').pop().split('.').pop(0).split('_') # foo will be "SNPs"
start=int(start)
end=int(end)


with open(SNP_vcf, newline='') as csvfile:
    csvread = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t',  quotechar='"')
    for myline in csvread: #reads csvfile line by line, storing array of cells into myline
        if(myline[0][0] == '#'):
            del(myline[0:9])
            for mycell in myline : 
                sampleIDs.append(mycell)
        else :
            chrom, pos, notID, ref, alt = myline[0:5] #get info of the SNP
            ID = chrom + "_" + pos + "." + ref + "_" + alt
            chrom = int(chrom)
            pos = int(pos) #these will be stored as str otherwise
            info = myline[7].split(';') # get info stored as string
            dinfo = {} # we need 'AF', not always at same position in string
            for v in info : # so convert the list into a dict to get it after
                t = v.split('=')
                if(len(t)>1) :
                    dinfo[t[0]] = t[1]
            mut_info[ID] = [[chrom, pos], #position info
                             [ref, alt], #nucletodie info
                             min(float(dinfo['AF']), 1-float(dinfo['AF'])),  #global allele frequency (min(x, 1-x) because some have freq>50%)
                            -1]
            mutations[ID] = [] #will be used to store the mutation in pop data
            del(myline[0:9])
            for mycell in myline : 
                mutations[ID].append(mapping[mycell]) # ONE HOT ENCODING
            mut_info[ID][3] = sum(map(adjust_count, mutations[ID]))
print("Read "+str(len(mutations))+" mutations from "+str(start)+" to "+str(end)+" on "+ chromosome)



tokeep = []
if threshold < 1 :
    for k,v in mut_info.items() :
        if v[2] >= threshold :
            tokeep.append(k)
else:
    for k,v in mut_info.items() :
        if v[3] >= threshold :
            tokeep.append(k)
        
print(str(len(tokeep))+" mutations passed the frequency threshold of "+str(threshold))


x = []
for k in tokeep :
    x.append(mutations[k])


x_arr = np.array(x)
x_tr = np.transpose(x_arr)
test_index = np.random.choice(range(len(x_tr)), math.floor(len(x_tr)/5), replace=False)
x_test = to_categorical(x_tr[test_index])
x_train = to_categorical(np.delete(x_tr, test_index, 0))
print("Total data is of shape "+str(x_tr.shape))
print("Training data is of shape "+str(x_train.shape))
print("Testing data is of shape " + str(x_test.shape))



input_size = len(tokeep)
hidden_1_size = math.ceil(0.5*input_size)
hidden_2_size = math.ceil(0.2*input_size)
code_size = math.ceil(0.05*input_size)

print("Input size: "+str(input_size))
print("First hidden layer size: "+str(hidden_1_size))
print("Second hidden layer size: "+str(hidden_2_size))
print("Code size: "+str(code_size))



input_data = Input(shape=x_train[1].shape)
f = Flatten()(input_data)
hidden_1 = Dense(hidden_1_size, activation='relu')(f)
e_drop = Dropout(0.4)(hidden_1)
hidden_2 = Dense(hidden_2_size, activation='relu')(e_drop)

code = Dense(code_size, activation='relu')(hidden_2)

hidden_2_rev = Dense(hidden_2_size, activation='relu')(code)
d_drop = Dropout(0.4)(hidden_2_rev)
hidden_1_rev = Dense(hidden_1_size, activation='relu')(d_drop)
output_data = Dense(input_size*4, activation='softmax')(hidden_1_rev) 
rshp_output_data = Reshape((-1,4))(output_data)



autoencoder = Model(input_data, rshp_output_data)
encoder = Model(input_data, code)
encoded_input = Input(shape=(code_size,))
decoder = Model(encoded_input, autoencoder.layers[-1](autoencoder.layers[-2](autoencoder.layers[-3](autoencoder.layers[-4](autoencoder.layers[-5](encoded_input))))) )

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()]) # when data is OHE


history = autoencoder.fit( x_train, x_train, epochs=1000, shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_test, x_test), 
                 callbacks=kcb.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=3, restore_best_weights=True) )

encoder.save(outdir + "encoder_fh_"+chromosome+"_"+str(start)+"_"+str(end))
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    516           else:
--> 517             values = ops.convert_to_tensor(
    518                 values,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    162           return func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 163       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    164 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1532     if dtype is not None and not dtype.is_compatible_with(value.dtype):
-> 1533       raise ValueError(
   1534           "Tensor conversion requested dtype %s for Tensor with dtype %s: %r" %

ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype resource for Tensor with dtype float32: <tf.Tensor 'dense_6/kernel/Read/ReadVariableOp:0' shape=(10000, 1250) dtype=float32>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-e76ca5687b87> in <module>
      1 ## SAVE OUPUT
      2 # autoencoder.save(outdir + "autoencoder_"+chromosome+"_"+str(start)+"_"+str(end))
----> 3 encoder.save(outdir + "encoder_fh_"+chromosome+"_"+str(start)+"_"+str(end))

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures, options, save_traces)
   2143     """
   2144     # pylint: enable=line-too-long
-> 2145     save.save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format,
   2146                     signatures, options, save_traces)
   2147 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/saving/save.py in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format, signatures, options, save_traces)
    147   else:
    148     with generic_utils.SharedObjectSavingScope():
--> 149       saved_model_save.save(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer,
    150                             signatures, options, save_traces)
    151 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/save.py in save(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, signatures, options, save_traces)
     88   with K.deprecated_internal_learning_phase_scope(0):
     89     with utils.keras_option_scope(save_traces):
---> 90       saved_nodes, node_paths = save_lib.save_and_return_nodes(
     91           model, filepath, signatures, options)
     92 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py in save_and_return_nodes(obj, export_dir, signatures, options, experimental_skip_checkpoint)
   1226 
   1227   _, exported_graph, object_saver, asset_info, saved_nodes, node_paths = (
-> 1228       _build_meta_graph(obj, signatures, options, meta_graph_def))
   1229   saved_model.saved_model_schema_version = (
   1230       pywrap_libexport.SAVED_MODEL_SCHEMA_VERSION)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py in _build_meta_graph(obj, signatures, options, meta_graph_def)
   1397 
   1398   with save_context.save_context(options):
-> 1399     return _build_meta_graph_impl(obj, signatures, options, meta_graph_def)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py in _build_meta_graph_impl(obj, signatures, options, meta_graph_def)
   1349                                 wrapped_functions)
   1350   object_saver = util.TrackableSaver(checkpoint_graph_view)
-> 1351   asset_info, exported_graph = _fill_meta_graph_def(
   1352       meta_graph_def, saveable_view, signatures,
   1353       options.namespace_whitelist, options.experimental_custom_gradients)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py in _fill_meta_graph_def(meta_graph_def, saveable_view, signature_functions, namespace_whitelist, save_custom_gradients)
    872             "to get the full error message.")
    873 
--> 874     saver_def = saver.to_proto()
    875     meta_graph_def.saver_def.CopyFrom(saver_def)
    876   graph_def = exported_graph.as_graph_def(add_shapes=True)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saving/functional_saver.py in to_proto(self)
    180         shape=[], dtype=dtypes.string, name="saver_filename")
    181     save_tensor = self._traced_save(filename_tensor)
--> 182     restore_op = self._traced_restore(filename_tensor).op
    183     return saver_pb2.SaverDef(
    184         filename_tensor_name=filename_tensor.name,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    883 
    884       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 885         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    886 
    887       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    931       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    932       initializers = []
--> 933       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    934     finally:
    935       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    757     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
    758     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
--> 759         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    760             *args, **kwds))
    761 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3064       args, kwargs = None, None
   3065     with self._lock:
-> 3066       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3067     return graph_function
   3068 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3461 
   3462           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3463           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3464           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3465 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3296     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3297     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3298         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3299             self._name,
   3300             self._python_function,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes, acd_record_initial_resource_uses)
   1005         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
   1006 
-> 1007       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1008 
   1009       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    666         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    667         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 668           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    669         return out
    670 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in bound_method_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   3983       if tf_inspect.ismethod(wrapped_fn):
   3984         wrapped_fn = six.get_unbound_function(wrapped_fn)
-> 3985       return wrapped_fn(weak_instance(), *args, **kwargs)
   3986 
   3987     # If __wrapped__ was replaced, then it is always an unbound function.

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saving/functional_saver.py in _traced_restore(self, file_prefix)
    200       autograph=False)
    201   def _traced_restore(self, file_prefix):
--> 202     restore_ops = self.restore(file_prefix)
    203     with ops.device("cpu:0"):
    204       with ops.control_dependencies(restore_ops.values()):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saving/functional_saver.py in restore(self, file_prefix, options)
    337       restore_ops = tf_function_restore()
    338     else:
--> 339       restore_ops = restore_fn()
    340 
    341     for callback in self._after_restore_callbacks:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saving/functional_saver.py in restore_fn()
    321       for device, saver in sorted(self._single_device_savers.items()):
    322         with ops.device(device):
--> 323           restore_ops.update(saver.restore(file_prefix, options))
    324 
    325       return restore_ops

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saving/functional_saver.py in restore(self, file_prefix, options)
    113     for saveable, restored_tensors in zip(self._saveable_objects,
    114                                           structured_restored_tensors):
--> 115       restore_ops[saveable.name] = saveable.restore(
    116           restored_tensors, restored_shapes=None)
    117     return restore_ops

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saving/saveable_object_util.py in restore(self, restored_tensors, restored_shapes)
    129     with ops.device(self._var_device):
    130       restored_tensor = array_ops.identity(restored_tensor)
--> 131       return resource_variable_ops.shape_safe_assign_variable_handle(
    132           self.handle_op, self._var_shape, restored_tensor)
    133 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py in shape_safe_assign_variable_handle(handle, shape, value, name)
    308     value_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(value)
    309   shape.assert_is_compatible_with(value_tensor.shape)
--> 310   return gen_resource_variable_ops.assign_variable_op(
    311       handle, value_tensor, name=name)
    312 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_resource_variable_ops.py in assign_variable_op(resource, value, name)
    152       pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
    153   # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
--> 154   _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
    155         "AssignVariableOp", resource=resource, value=value, name=name)
    156   return _op

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    542                     (input_name, op_type_name, observed))
    543           if input_arg.type != types_pb2.DT_INVALID:
--> 544             raise TypeError("%s expected type of %s." %
    545                             (prefix, dtypes.as_dtype(input_arg.type).name))
    546           else:

TypeError: Input 'resource' of 'AssignVariableOp' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of resource.
```

I tried specifying the `dtype` when creating x_train and x_test, but it does not affect this type mismatch error. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: When I copy and paste your code I get `NameError: name 'x' is not defined.` Also `chromosome` is not defined anywhere in your example.

Comment: @gobrewers14 included the data file

Comment: `sampleIDs`, `mutations`, `mut_info`, what are these things? They are not defined anywhere. Your code is not reproducible.

Comment: @gobrewers14 my apologies, I had forgotten a chunk while copying and pasting.

Comment: I ran your code without issue. It trains for 24 epochs before exiting b/c of early stopping and then saves the model. I ran the code in this env: 2013 MacBook Pro, macOS Big Sur 11.6, 2GHz Core i7, Python 3.8.8, Tensorflow 2.6.0. Try creating an isolated environment (in a docker container or a virtualbox/vmware virtual machine) and see if the problem persists there.